# Monitor keyboard events inside process (Process Wide)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I can install system wide keyboard monitor by the below instructions:

```
CGEventRef eventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type,
    CGEventRef event, void *userData)
{
}

CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap,
    kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault,
    kCGEventKeyDown,
    &eventCallback,
    NULL);
if(eventTap)
{
    CFRunLoopSourceRef eventRunLoopSourceRef =
        CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, eventTap, 0);
    CFRelease(eventTap);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), eventRunLoopSourceRef,
        kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    CFRelease(eventRunLoopSourceRef);
}
```

The disadvantage of this code is that it requires to activate "Universal access" in "System Preferences" and also monitor all processes (I do not need it).

I want to monitor keyboard events **inside my process**. How it possible and is it required to activate "Universal access"? Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `NSEvent`'s `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`

```
self.eventMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask 
    handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
        NSLog( @"keyDown event!" );
        return event;
    }];
```

See [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask%3ahandler%3a).  This doesn't require Universal Access to be turned on.

Comment: What happens if I dont have access to "self"? I have been written a dylib which injected into other processes, In carbon apps like InDesign, I use Carbon Events and have no problen, but in cocoa apps like TextEdit how can I use your approach inside a dylib?

Comment: addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler: returns an id, which you need to save somewhere so you can remove the monitor later (with removeMonitor:).  In my example, I made it a property on a class, but it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have to monitor other processes then you should be able to use normal events to look at the keyboard.

In Carbon, install a handler for `kEventRawKeyDown` (say) of `kEventClassKeyboard`, e.g. at the application or window levels.

In Cocoa, implement `keyDown:` or whatever method you require on a subclass of `NSResponder` such as your `NSApplication` subclass or a particular `NSWindow` subclass.

Comment: What happens if I dont have access to NSApplication? I have been written a dylib which injected into other processes, In carbon apps like InDesign, I use Carbon Events and have no problen, but in cocoa apps like TextEdit how can I implement keyDown: inside a dylib?

Answer (score 2):

```
ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0 };
GetCurrentProcess( & psn );
CGEventTapCreateForPSN( & psn, ... );
```

This is the process-wide manner for listening to events only in the current process, not system-wide.

Comment: I have not tested it yet, But It seems it is a really good answer. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

In Cocoa, I think you'd want to subclass NSApplication and override `-[NSApplication sendEvent:]`.

Comment: What happens if I dont have access to "NSApplication"? I have been written a dylib which injected into other processes, In carbon apps like InDesign, I use Carbon Events and have no problen, but in cocoa apps like TextEdit how can I monitor keydown inside a dylib?