# CoreFoundation alternative for addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-foundation

The **addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask** function is member of NSEvent class and installs an event monitor that receives copies of events posted to this application before they are dispatched. 
What is the **Core Foundation** alternative of It?
I do not want to enable **accessibility access**.
See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437345/monitor-keyboard-events-inside-process-process-wide).